# How to apply gesture handling greedy for Embedded Maps in IFrame (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-markers

I want to allow single finger touch for mobile devices instead of using double fingers for gestures and for web need scrolling feature  on an embedded map.

I found out that I can use gesture handling "greedy" or "cooperative" to achieve this but I am not able to understand where to apply it in my code.

Code:

```
const MY_API = configData.googleMapKey;

  let _url = `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=${MY_API}&origin=${queryPickup}&destination=${queryDrop}`;
 
  return(

        <div>
          <iframe  frameBorder="0" width="100%" height="350" style={{ border: 0 }} src={_url}>
          </iframe>
        </div>
    
  );

};
```